# How to map image coordinates to flutter coordinates with scaling awareness

Tags: flutter, dart

I have an image with a rectangle drown in it, I know the position and the size of the rectangle. I could have different images with different and multiple elements like this.

I want to position a Widget, in a way that perfecly overlaps the rectangle in the image background, this means that I need a way to map the position and scale of my rectangle to the flutter coordinates of my containing widget.

I came up with a Stack with the actual Image on the bottom, with a BoxFit.cover fit, and a Positioned with my Container inside on top of it.
It should work with every aspect ratio and pixel density.
I need some formula to fill those question marks.

Thank you.

```dart
class ImageWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  static const Offset imageTargetStart = Offset(302, 281);
  static const Size imageTargetSize = Size(441, 57);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      fit: StackFit.expand,
      children: <Widget>[
        Image.asset(
          'assets/sample_image.png',
          fit: BoxFit.cover,
        ),
        Positioned(
//          left: ??,
//          top: ??,
          child: Container(
//            width: ??,
//            height: ??,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(border: Border.all(color: Colors.red), color: Colors.greenAccent),
          ),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: sorry, you cannot do that - all you can do is to draw your image and rectangle in a `CustomPainter`

Comment: Oh, no! Can I at least draw flutter widgets inside a CustomPainter?

Comment: no. not really, in theory yes, but it is not so easy...